# PHP table. Show total before the new group

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a problem about showing total in groups.

Here is my scenario, I have a report grouped by area and by product.

What I already have is the row for area group.

What I want to do is to show the total qty of product per area before the row for the next group. Currently, it shows the total after every row.

Here is my code.

```
<?php if (isset($summaryPerArea)): ?>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table id="" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Area</th>
          <th>Material</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php 
        $prevArea = '';
        $total = 0;
        $currentQty = 0;
      ?>
      <?php foreach ($summaryPerArea as $key => $value): ?>
        <?php $currentQty = $value['totalQty']; ?>
        <?php $total += $value['totalQty']; ?>
        <?php if ($value['area'] != $prevArea): ?>
          <tr class="bg-info">
            <?php if ($key != 0) {$total = $currentQty;} ?>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo $value['area']; ?></td>
            <?php $prevArea = $value['area']; ?>
          </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value['area']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['material']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['totalQty']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php if ($value['area'] == $prevArea): ?>
          <tr class="bg-success">
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>       
      <?php endforeach ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
<?php endif ?>
```

query:

```
SELECT d.SOffcNm as area,
           c.ProdNm as material,
           SUM(Qty) as totalQty
    FROM   BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H as a

           INNER JOIN BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_D as b
           ON a.TransCtr = b.TransCtr

           INNER JOIN BigESales.dbo.tbl_Materials as c
           ON b.Material = c.ExtMatGrp

           INNER JOIN BigESales.dbo.tbl_Customers as d
           ON a.CustCode = d.CustCode

           WHERE d.SOffc LIKE ISNULL('%' + @area + '%', d.SOffc) 
           AND a.DtRcv BETWEEN @DtRcvFrom AND @DtRcvTo
GROUP BY   d.SOffcNm,
           c.ProdNm
ORDER BY   d.SOffcNm asc
```

current result:

[image: Table Screenshot]

Thankyou. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a complete question because a) you never showed us the MySQL query and b) you never showed us the current output.

Comment: You could update that area total value with Javascript later. Assign an `id` to the table cell, keep track of the running totals, create a Javascript array and during `window.onload`, transfer the data from the Javascript array to the table cells.

Comment: Hi Tim! I have now added the sql query and there is a screenshot included. THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your code according to the comments in the code below (only the foreach part)

```
  <?php foreach ($summaryPerArea as $key => $value): ?>
    <?php if ($value['area'] != $prevArea and $prevArea): // show total when changing area from second area onward ?>
      <tr class="bg-success">
        <td colspan="3"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php $total = 0; // reset the total after displaying it ?>
    <?php endif; ?>       
    <?php if ($value['area'] != $prevArea):// show area header at every area change ?>
      <tr class="bg-info">
        <td colspan="3"><?php echo $value['area']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php //$currentQty = $value['totalQty']; // does not needed ?>
    <?php $total += $value['totalQty']; ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $value['area']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['material']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['totalQty']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $prevArea = $value['area']; // set prevArea to the processed row ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  <?php // show the last total ?>
  <tr class="bg-success">
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

notice that the order of the rows are repeated as follows:

```
--area total--
--area header--
--area item--
```

and followed by:

```
--area total--
```

on the first foreach, `prevArea` is still `''` so the first condition in the `--area total--` (`and $prevArea`) would result in `false`, so that the `--area total--` is suppressed, but the `--area header--` does not have that condition, so the `--area header--` is not suppressed.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help am05hz! It is now working with your code. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a different syntax of php, using if(condition){code};

If I understood your problem, I make a different solution, I controll if the next is different from the value that i use now, because if it was different you need to print.

I rewrite your code like this:

```
<tbody>
  <?php 
    $prevArea = 'AnElementLikeFlag';
    $total = 0;
    $currentQty = 0;
  ?>
  <?php foreach ($summaryPerArea as $key => $value): ?>
    <?php $currentQty = $value['totalQty']; ?>
    <?php if ($value['area'] != $prevArea && $value['area']!="AnElementLikeFlag"): ?>

      <tr class="bg-success">
        <td colspan="3"><?php echo $total; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bg-info">
        <td colspan="3"><?php echo $value['area']; ?></td>
        <?php $prevArea = $value['area']; ?>
      </tr>
    <?php $total=0; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $total += $value['totalQty']; ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $value['area']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['material']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value['totalQty']; ?></td>
    </tr>

  <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
```

I hope I help you and I maybe make an error.

P.S. You print the total every time, because there is a if condition that it is not necessery